# AngularJS + API call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

Trying to  understand how AngularJS works, doing my first API calls, when I got stuck.
I want to do 2 API calls, but I can't seem to make it work.

After the first **$http.get** I want to do an another call (using the information from the previous call) but that doesn't work for some reason. (I get no alert)

The city and country are working perfectly after the first .get

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('weather', []);

app.controller("weatherCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://ipinfo.io/json").then(function(response) {
        $scope.city = response.data.city;
        $scope.country = response.data.country;  

        var apiKey = "";
        var apiCall = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + response.data.city + "&APPID=" + apiKey;   

        $http.get(apiCall).then(function(responsew) {
            // $scope.temperature would get a value here
            alert("1")
        });
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="weather" ng-controller="weatherCtrl">
    <h1 class="text-center">Weather</h1>
    <h2 class="text-center">{{city}}, {{country}}</h2>
    <h2 class="text-center">{{temperature}} °C</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you need to add the http protocol to your second url.

Comment: Yeah. You think just right.. How lame of me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promise to call the request after another which is the recommended way to do,

Another thing is you are missing the **`http`** part in the second request

**Code:**

```
app.controller("weatherCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

    function infoReq() {
        return $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: 'http://ipinfo.io/json'
        })
    }

    function weatherReq() {
        var apiKey = "";
        var apiCall = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $scope.city + "&APPID=" + apiKey;
        return $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: apiCall,
        })
    }

    $scope.makeRequest = function () {
        infoReq()
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.city = response.data.city;
                $scope.country = response.data.country;
                return weatherReq();
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            })


    }

})
```

Comment: Just one question. What is the purpose of the $scope.makeRequest? Wouldn't be enough just to call infoReq()?

Answer (score 0):

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $scope.city + "&APPID=" + apiKey;
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

You can use the above http service to make the request inside your angularjs controller.